# How do I update a certain value in LocalStorage inside a nested object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I set it like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
    myState: {
        data: {
            website: "google.com",
            visited: false,
            count: 0
        }
    }
})
```

If I want to change myState.data.visited to true, what should I do?

Comment: Read it first, change the object, then write the result. There's no other way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the data, change it and save it again.

```
    chrome.storage.local.get('storageKey', function(result) {
      //data.visited will be in the result object for a specific key. You can change data.visited 
      //to be true here. After changing it to true you can save it again under 
      //the key 'storageKey' or any key you like.

      chrome.storage.local.set({storageKey: result});
    });
```

Comment: I just want to mention the fact that one should be mindful of which object being returned from the chrome storage, by inspecting them, as accessing unintended nested objects can lead to apparently silent errors.